# Bash "$@" does not substitute variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am sorry because this probably has been asked, but I cannot google these special characters properly.

I have the following `script.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

export c=23;

"$@"
```

And when I call it with:

```bsh
(export a=231; export b=45; ./script.sh echo "$a, $b, $c")
```

The variable `$c` does not appear in the output:

```bsh
231, 45,
```

How can I create a passthrough script that adds extra variables to the executed command?

---

Edit again for the full context:

The usage is that I have a docker container. The dockerfile gets the COMMIT_HASH at build time. Then I want to call `java app.jar` (for container run) and this running process should have the COMMIT_HASH variable configured.

So in the `Dockerfile`, I have something like this now:

```
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash \n java -Dapp.info.commit-hash=\"${COMMIT_HASH}\" -jar /app.jar \"\$@\"" > ./entrypoint.sh

...

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

As you can see, with this setup I cannot configure arguments for the jar. But I cannot find out how to be able to create the full command outside the container and have the variables substituted into it.

This is why, ideally, I would like to have a script that makes it available to specify extra variables, but also have the variables configured as default.

That is why the final script (now without the Dockerfile usage) would look something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

export COMMIT_HASH=a982321bc232d;

"$@"
```

Then merging them together with:

```bsh
# read from a .env file or something - these are dynamic values
export PORT=8081;
export FRONTEND_URL=http://example.com;

java -Dapp.info.commit-hash="${COMMIT_HASH}" -Dserver.port="${PORT}" -jar /app.jar --FRONTEND_URL="${FRONTEND_URL}"
```

Comment: Once the arguments reaches your script and you set `c`, the string has already had its values substituted into it (this is done by the calling shell before starting your script). Could you give more context to this issue? What you want to do is somewhat irregular, and I'm thinking there are better ways to achieve what you're aiming at.  Do you, for example, want to call some explicit command and add an argument to that? Can you show a more specific example?

Comment: The usage is that I have a docker container. The dockerfile gets the COMMIT_HASH at build time. Then I want to call `java app.jar` (for container run) and this running process should have the COMMIT_HASH variable configured.

Comment: But it would be better if I could call `java -Dspring.commit-hash=$COMMIT_HASH jar` instead, because it requires less config for the server.

Comment: If you have clarifications to your question, please add these to the question itself by editing it. This makes it easier for us to see what you mean and you have greater control over formatting. Comments are temporary and may disappear at any moment.  Show what happens, and show what you want to happen.

Comment: Thanks, edited accordingly.

Comment: I edited the question for further context on why this is needed, hope it clears it up a bit.

Comment: how do you run that wrapper script, then? How do you run that last script? If you have a wrapper script that has `export CONFIG_HASH=whatever`, which then calls another script that has `somecommand foo bar "$CONFIG_HASH" ... `, then the variable should be available there in the second script. I don't understand why you'd need to pass a command line (with the reference to `$CONFIG_HASH`) for another script to parse and evaluate. Why not just have the final script, the one that eventual runs `java` there, add the command line option?

Comment: The last script is technically what `docker-compose` does with its `environment` variables and `run` command. There is no `COMMIT_HASH` available there, because it is built into the image. But at image build time, I don't know these other variables (like `PORT`, `FRONTEND_URL`), as these will be decided later on. So the key point is that these `COMMIT_HASH` and the 2 other property have to be available in the same shell somehow. Hope this clears it up.

Comment: I tried to ask how you're going to run those scripts. I can't see the command lines there. (Nor names for the scripts, which would help in seeing what runs what.) You said you "cannot find out how to be able to create the full command outside the container and have the variables substituted into it", but you can you build that command by hand? What's the command you eventually want to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to escape the sigil for `$c` when invoking the script, and in the script `eval "$@"` to get a 2nd round of variable expansion.

```bsh
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

export c=23;

eval "$@"
```

```bsh
$ (export a=231; export b=45; bash -x ./script.sh echo "$a, $b, \$c")
+ export c=23
+ c=23
+ eval echo '231, 45, $c'
++ echo 231, 45, 23
231, 45, 23
```

Or, single quote the code to send to the script and let the script's shell expand all the variables:

```bsh
$ (export a=231; export b=45; bash -x ./script.sh 'echo "$a, $b, $c"')
+ export c=23
+ c=23
+ eval 'echo "$a, $b, $c"'
++ echo '231, 45, 23'
231, 45, 23
```